# What is the right way to declaratively render to a canvas with Preact?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, preact

I am learning Preact by converting a vanilla ECMAScript 6 toy application from an imperative approach to a reactive approach. The toy application includes the ability to render a function as a canvas, when the function happens to map points to colors.

What is the correct way to write a component which declaratively renders to a canvas? I'm not asking Preact to take a diff of the canvas contents; rather, I just want to generate pixels instead of a VDOM node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where refs step in:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks'

export function Canvas() {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const context = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');

        context.fillStyle = '#f00';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 120, 120);
    }, []);
  
    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
}
```

Refs are references to DOM nodes, allowing you to read and/or edit as you see fit.

In the above example, we create a new ref using `useRef()`, setting `null` as the initial value. Then, we attach our ref to the `<canvas>` element, giving it a backing node. Finally, in our `useEffect()`, we can access that node using `.current` upon our ref. There you can read and/or write as you see fit.

Docs (there are a couple sub-links you can follow to get more information too): https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks#useref

Comment: This works beautifully and flawlessly for single frames. I would imagine that this would be a great addition/example for the official docs. Thank you!

Comment: It also works for animations! I'm updating the state by passing a callback to `window.requestAnimationFrame()`, and my animation callback can handle a variable framerate directly.